# Laravel attribute set catch exception

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

This is a method I have on a model:

```
return Attribute::make(
    set: fn ($value) => CarbonInterval::fromString($value)->spec(),
);
```

However, if the value is some gibberish this throws `Carbon\Exceptions\InvalidIntervalException;`

What's the best way to catch the error here and leave the property unchanged?

Answer (score 0):

You can use php `try-catch` here as:

```
// Try this 
try {
  return Attribute::make(
    set: fn ($value) => CarbonInterval::fromString($value)->spec(),
  );
}

//catch exception if trying fails
catch(Exception $e) {
  echo 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Hey! This is what I tried first and for some reason the exception keeps being thrown. That's why I made the thread, thought laravel's set interval works in some other way that can't work with try-catch in this manner.

Comment: So you are saying that, it never goes to the catch block? and throws exception anyway?

Comment: Yes, I've tried with catching the general `\Exception` and with catching Carbon's InvalidIntervalException - both no luck. I know this is the right block of code, because if I remote the whole thing the exception goes away.

Answer (score 0):

can you try with this.

```
return Attribute::make(
    set: fn ($value) => $value ? CarbonInterval::fromString($value)->spec() : null,
);
```

Comment: if $value is not a valid Carbon Interval string it throws the exception, not only if it's not set or empty.

Answer (score 0):

I did it by adding a try-catch block to validate the input in the first place (in a Request Validation) and then pass to the attribute set. Apparently try-catch doesn't work there.

```
'interval'     => [
                'required',
                function($attribute, $value, $fail) {
                    try {
                        CarbonInterval::fromString($value)->spec();
                    } catch (\Exception $e) {
                        $fail('The interval must follow a valid pattern. E.g. "1 month" or "3 months 19 days"');
                    }
                }
            ],
```